# IE9 png and background property

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, png

I have an issue here, I'm working on a project which is properly working in firefox and chrome. 
Now I'm testing in IE. I thought with all the advertising about IE9, it would look great, or at least not break anything.

I have several problems though :

I use some png images. And even if the images are showing, I have a little red cross above it. And I really don't understand why ... you can see it here : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=173809Sanstitre.png

In the same pic, you can see that the property background-repeat : repeat-x is not working. The funny thing about this, is that at the beginning it is working, and when the page finishes to load, it screw everything : http://hpics.li/feebab4

Does anyone have an idea what can be the cause of that ? 
Thanks

EDIT : Oh also, sometimes IE9 is adding some stuff in the inline of my images like :

style="width: 171px; height: 52px; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://localhost/Sites/promenadeSteCatherine/wp-content/themes/promenadeSteCatherine/img/menuGauche/titre_projet1.png', sizingMethod='scale');" alt="projet" src="x.gif"

It might be a problem with a plugin I'm using in wordpress, but I don't see which one, here is the plugins I'm using : 
 Advanced Custom Fields
 Contact form
 tinyMCE
 user role editor
 wp-slidinglogindashboardpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both properties are fully supported by IE9+. Are you using any png 'fixes' for IE6, like JavaScript replacement or DX filters? They could be interefering.

Comment: Hey, 
I've just seen that one of my wordpress plugin was using a png fix, I'm going to deactivate it to see if that works. 
Let you know

Comment: But what happens now in older browsers