# png logo will have white borders on IE9

Tags: html, css, layout

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, we have our upper top navigation bar as blue area,  and I am displaying our logo inside the blue area , using the following code:-

```
   <a class="brand" href="~/Home/Index/"> <img alt="Group" src="~/Content/logo_CMYK.png" /> </a>
```

but on IE9 it will show white boarder around the logo as follow:-

[image]

while on IE10, Firefox and Chrome , logo will have blue boarder as follow, and will work fine :-

[image]

can anyone advice how I can fix this layout issue ?
Thanks

**Edit**
Here is the CSS retrived from the IE F12:-
[image]

Comment: Do you have a url or jsfiddle showing this? This reminds me of this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/12438248/427684

Comment: no I do not have a link, as my system is still not published on the internet..

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a white border, it's the background which is white.
You may try this code:

```
a, img {
   background: transparent;   
   zoom: 1;
}
```

It declares that the background of your image is transparent.

If you could set up a jsbin.com example, someone might just show the correct answer instead of guessing a fix.

Comment: I modified my code for the <img> tag as follow;    <a class="brand" href="~/Home/Index/"> <img alt="Group" src="~/Content/logo_CMYK.png" style="background: transparent;   zoom: 1;" /> </a>
But this did not change any thing.. can you advice ?

Comment: I also tried style="background-color:transparent; . and nothing changed

Comment: could you provide an example on [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/) with the same image ? This way everyone is able to reproduce the error.

Comment: sorry I have not used this before I am not sure how to add the example. but I have edited my original question with the CSS setting using IE F12 tool, which shows what are the CSS involved when I mark the logo . thanks